# asp.net core in vs 2017 minify each js file for each view

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a mvc core project ,and i have a js file for each view on views folder.
How to globally minify each js file of each view into wwwroot/views/.. folder with use bundleconfig.json like this :

```
 {
   "outputFileName": "wwwroot/views/*.min.js",
   "inputFiles": [
     "Views/**/jquery/*.js"
   ],
   "minify": {
     "enabled": true,
     "renameLocals": true
   }
 }
```

I don't want bundle all js file in one file.

Answer (score 0):

Use following extension it may help you to resolve this issue.

https://github.com/ravikumar77/BundlerMinifier